# How can I simplify this: $(\neg p \rightarrow p)= p$?

Tags: logic

How can I simplify this: $(\neg p \rightarrow p)= p$?

I already tried every rule I know, but I can't find the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Using $p\rightarrow q= \lnot p\lor q$, you have $\lnot p \rightarrow p = p \lor p = p$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is true, then $\lnot p\rightarrow p$ is also true, because "false implies true" is true.

If $p$ is false, then $\lnot p\rightarrow p$ is also false, because "true implies false" is false.

So $p$ and $\lnot p\rightarrow p$ are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that both expressions agree for all values of $p$.

If $p=T$, then L.H.S. = $(F \rightarrow T)=T=p$.

If $p=F$, then L.H.S. = $(T \rightarrow F)=F=p$.